# Angular update ng-src from promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have an API function which retrieves a logo (.png). I can't use the direct url to the png as I need to send a basic authentication header. The API already handles this one.

How can I update the ng-src attribute? The API is promise based.

The actual problem is that I have a table with multiple items where I need to fetch the logo for each, so I can't add a variable in the $scope. Any opinions?

Comment: show some code to understand the situation better.

Comment: Since you already have an array of items in scope you can use this items to store logo as well.

Answer (score 3):

per @Yury Tarabanko's comment you can use the API to fetch your data and then write it back to the object.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list">
    <img ng-init="getImgSrc(obj)" ng-src="{{obj.imgSrc}}">
```

Your controller method would be something like this:

```
$scope.getImgSrc = function(obj)
{
    $http.get(obj.imgUrl, <params>)
    .then( function(rsp){ obj.imgSrc = rsp; })
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your images aren't on a CDN somewhere so you may need to change up how the response is converted to something useful that the `img` tag can process.  Not knowing how your setup works this is a very basic example of processing async data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code I'm using totally faked [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bjhf7qPwvWqNm475RsuC).

Controller code (this should be better moved to a service)

```
app.controller('ViewModel', ['$http', function($http) {
  // async function that loads and saves image
  const loadImg = item => {
    $http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(res => {
      const user = res.data.results[0]
      item.logo = user.picture.medium
    })
  }


  // faking items
  this.items = Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map((_, i) => {
    const item = {
      id: i,
      title: `Item ${i+1}`
    };

    loadImg(item); // run loading for every item.
    return item;
  })
}])
```

Template

```
<table ng-controller="ViewModel as vm">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by item.id">
    <td><img ng-src="{{item.logo}}"/></td>
    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that *randomuser.me/api* is great!